# UIButton inside UIImageView does not respond to taps

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uibutton

I have a scroll view, which has an image view with an image as a subview, and the image view has a `UIButton` as one of its subviews. The problem is, I am not able to click on the button. I can SEE the button, but I cannot tap on it.

Can someone tell me what is it that I am messing up? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Below is the code:

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];    
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.jpg"]];
scrollView.delegate = self;
self.view = scrollView;

// add invisible buttons
[self addInvisibleButtons];
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
```

`addInvisibleButtons` has the following code:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonHandler) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
[button setTitle:@"point" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
[self.imageView addSubview:button];
```

Comment: You could try and see if bringSubviewToFront: works after adding the button to the image view? Or same could be applied to the image view within your scroll view.

Comment: Infact, I tried that and it didn't work. userInteractionEnabled did the trick.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

`UIImageView` has `userInteractionEnabled` set to `NO`/ `false` by default.

You are adding the button as a subview to the image view. You should set it to `YES` / `true`.

Comment: Cool, that worked. But, when I do this, the target/action method for the button is getting called twice (I had an NSLog inside the `buttonHandler` selector to confirm this). Why is that happening?

Comment: Shouldn't `UIControlEventAllEvents` be `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`?

Comment: Indeed yes! I made that change when I was trying to meddle with something else and forgot to undo the change. Great. Thanks!

Comment: wise words.! aka `userInteractionEnabled`

Answer (score 4):

May I ask why are you adding invisible `UIButtons` to `UIImageView`?

Seems like a bad practice, notice `Interface Builder` doesn't allow you to add `UIButton` inside them.

If you want an image with touch handling, you can:

```
UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonHandler) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
[button setTitle:@"point" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0)];

[scrollView addSubview:button];
```

Comment: Because I want to implement the HTML image-map kind of feature on the iPad, where clicking on several regions of the image does different things.

Comment: I already tried that too, and the problem is when you zoom in and out of the map, the button location gets misplaced and you don't get the tap action where it is supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

You can have **addInvisibleButtons** implementation as

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonHandler) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
[button setTitle:@"point" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.imageView addSubview:button];
```

If you want to have `UIButton` as completely invisible then you need to remove a line 
`[button setTitle:@"point" forState:UIControlStateNormal];` 
since it use to show text on `UIButton` which make it visible.

This may resolve your issue.