# UIButton is not responding when added to a UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to add a button to a UIImageView with a transparent background - the button is shown ok but is not responding. (takePictureClicked is not called)

My code:

```
cameraController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
cameraController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
cameraController.delegate = self;
cameraController.allowsEditing=YES;
cameraController.showsCameraControls = NO;
cameraController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
cameraController.toolbarHidden = YES;
// overlay on top of camera lens view
UIImageView *cameraOverlayView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera_overlay.png"]];
cameraOverlayView.alpha = 0.0f;
//Take picture button
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"714-camera.png"];
[button setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(takePictureClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.frame = CGRectMake(cameraOverlayView.center.x-16,cameraOverlayView.frame.size.height,32,32);
[cameraOverlayView addSubview:button];
[cameraOverlayView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[cameraOverlayView bringSubviewToFront:button];
cameraController.cameraOverlayView = cameraOverlayView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you create a `UIView` where you can add different ui elements like `UIButton` or `UIImageView`. An `UIImageView` is just for `UIImages` and not for adding any other stuff on it. Create another `UIView` which will hold all the elements in it.

[Like this post describes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6164508/1141395), even `Interface Builder` doesn't allow you to add a `UIButton` to an `UIImageView`.

Comment: How can I do that? which type should I create and put the UIImage and UIButton on it? If I understood correctly I need to put both controls in a parent control which will be added to the UIImagePickerController as overlay?

Comment: I didn't work with UIImagePickerController but normally you have a `UIView` as parent which includes everything else and the `UIView` itself can be added to your `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to able the user interaction:

```
[cameraOverlayView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

You have also the checkbox in Interface Builder if you are using it.

This is needed because for **default**, the `UIImageView` has the *user interaction `disabled`.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `userInteractionEnabled` to the `UIImageView`?

try with:

```
cameraOverlayView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```